# How to execute a tkinter in the middle of a Python program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a database that includes students' information. In the middle of the program, I need a Tkinter window to be open. How should I open a GUI window in the middle of a Python program?!
The window must include a search box (Entry) by n_number (dictionary value) to show the name (dictionary key related to the entered n_number) of the student and a list of all students. At the same time that I can search by n_number, I need the list of all students, so I can click on each name and see the courses he/she got. I don't know how can I make a clickable list in Tkinter.

...

```
 from tkinter import *


 class Student:
     def __init__(self):
         self.name = ""
         self.n_number = None
         self.courses = {}
         self.students = {}

     def add_stu(self, name, n_number):
         self.students[name] = n_number

     def find_stu(self, n_number):
         return list(self.students.keys())[list(self.students.values()).index(n_number)]

     def add_course(self, cname, score):
         self.courses[cname] = score
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Just [`.destroy`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python/) your root element after you get what you want from user, consider following simple example:

```
from tkinter import *
user_input = ""
def get_and_destroy():
    global user_input
    user_input = entry.get()
    root.destroy()
print("Before tkinter")
root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="Go", command=get_and_destroy)
btn.pack()
mainloop()
print("After tkinter")
print("User typed:",user_input)
```

As you might observe `destroy`-ing cause breaking from `mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with the `Tkinter` and call it when you need the pop up.

Comment: Thank you. It was the first solution that came to my mind. I did but after I wanted the search button to be related to the search function, I didn't know what should I do to see the name that related to the entered n_number in the new window (Frame).

Answer (score 0):

To start a Tkinter in the middle of a program, you just declare a Tk() and end it with a .mainloop(). This will stop it from continuing until the window is closed:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

print('hi')
time.sleep(1)
print('Tkinter starting in:')
time.sleep(1)
print('3')
time.sleep(1)
print('2')
time.sleep(1)
print('1')

root = Tk()
# Put GUI elements in here
root.mainloop()

print('WHY DID YOU LEAVE ME')
```

As for clickable lists, I would suggest looking into ttk and [ttk treeview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTqDYmfccQU)

Answer (score -1):

To add another window you do Tk()

```
from tkinter import *
wn = Tk()
wn.title('Window 1')
window = Tk()
window.title('Window2')
```